# Refactor loops and conditions with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a code snippet like:

```
List<Ticket> lowestPriceTickets(List<Info> infos, Ticket lowestPriceTicket) {
    List<Ticket> allLowestPriceTickets = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Info info : infos)
    {
        if (info.getTicketTypeList() != null)
        {
            for (Ticket ticket : info.getTicketTypeList())
            {
                if (lowestPriceTicket.getCode().order() == ticket.getCode().order())
                {
                    allLowestPriceTickets.add(ticket);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return allLowestPriceTickets;
}
```

I'm trying to refactor it using Java 8 streams but stucked after

```
infos.stream()
                .filter(info -> info.getTicketTypeList() != null)
                .map(Info::getTicketTypeList)
```

because I would like to filter each `Ticket` but see `Stream<List<Ticket>>`,
could someone suggest please how this method should be accomplished?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` in between to convert the list of `Ticket` objects into stream so that you can filter the Tickets. You can refer the below code (with inline comments) to achieve the result using streams:

```
List<Ticket> ticketsList = infos.stream()
   .filter(info -> info.getTicketTypeList() != null)//filter the list if null
   .map(info -> info.getTicketTypeList())//get the tickettype list
   .flatMap(ticketsList -> ticketsList.stream())//convert to stream of tickets
   .filter(lowestPriceTicket -> 
       lowestPriceTicket.getCode().order() == 
          ticket.getCode().order())//check if it matches with the given ticket
   .collect(Collectors.toList());//now collect it to a List<Ticket>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly I wanted!